# What am I missing in port forwarding?

Tags: router, ports, port-forwarding

I am trying to  forward  a specific  port on my router with listening to that port number, but when I run canyouseeme tool, it shows the connection is refused.

I made the inbound rule, no firewall no anti-virus working. 
My friend told me that the error its self is not an ISP issue. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: There aren't enough details here to be able to say. Could be a problem with the config, invisible blocking on the ISP side, etc...

Comment: What port are you trying to forward? What router model do you have? Is anything actually listening on the other end or are you just turning on port forwarding just to see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

instead of a port foward rule try to publish the full internal ip address.
Normally all routers allow to set a dmz host (1 host).
If it works then you can retry the port forwarding rule as something might be wrong.
If it does not works try to see if your ISP is blocking or providing you private address ranges instead of public.